# Find packages including cronjob or other automated scripts

Tags: linux, security, debian, system-administration

Debian auditing package prioritization [guidelines](https://www.debian.org/security/audit/packages) recommend to check the packages containing

> Anything which contains a cronjob or other automated script which runs with root privileges.

How can I find the packages which meet the aforementioned rule?

Answer (score 1):

For cronjobs, packages have cronjobs listed in their files:

```
$ dpkg-query -L mdadm | grep cron
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/mdadm
/etc/cron.d
/etc/cron.d/mdadm
```

So you could do:

```
ALL_PKGS=$(dpkg -l | awk '{ print $2 }' | tail -n +6)
for PKG in $ALL_PKGS; do
    if dpkg-query -L $PKG | grep -q /etc/cron; then
        echo $PKG
    fi
done
```

Note that this `tail -n +6` is because of the extra output from `dpkg -l`, you might have to do a slightly different adjustment to get all packages.

Comment: That works for cronjob, but what about other automated script?